# Swiftのグローバル変数がLazyになる件

Tags: swift

Swiftの変数や定数が、何故か勝手にlazyになる問題で、グローバル変数も同様にlazyになるのですが、より詳しく解説しているものはありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Swift Programming Language: Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)
Appleの公式文書です。この中の「Global and Local Variables」の項。「Note」を引用します。

> NOTE
>
> Global constants and variables are always computed lazily, in a
>   similar manner to Lazy Stored Properties. Unlike lazy stored
>   properties, global constants and variables do not need to be marked
>   with the lazy modifier.
>
> Local constants and variables are never computed lazily.

グローバル変数は、最初から、かつ常にLazyということですね。